# For every $n\in \Bbb{N}$, either $n$ is even or $n-1$ is even (Must use Induction)

Tags: proof-explanation

I have gotten a lot of the proof done so far but I am now stuck: Pf: Let $n\in\Bbb{N}$. $P(n)$ is the statement, "$n$ is even or $n-1$ is even" 
Base Case ($n=1$): $n=1$  and $1-1=1$ so $n-1$ is even. $P(2)$ holds. 
Induction: Let $k\in\Bbb{N}$. We will assume $P(k)$ is true, $k$ is even or $k-1$ is even, in order to prove $P(k+1)$. Then $k+1$ is even or $(k+1)-1$ is even.
My next step was going to be to either multiply or add $(k+1)$ and $(k+1)-1$ together since with natural numbers you can do that but I am not sure what to do after that...

Comment: You ought to have a clear, single definition of the word "even" which you use consistently. Without that, the proof will be full of hand-waving no matter what you do.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go through this line by line.

> Base Case ($n=1$): $n=1$ and $1-1=\color{red}{1}$ so $n-1$ is even.

I think this is just a typo.  $1-1=0$, and that is even.

> $P(2)$ holds.

You probably mean $P(1)$ holds.  That is what you proved.

> Induction: Let $k∈N$. We will assume $P(k)$ is true, [that is,] $k$ is even or $k-1$ is even, in order to prove $P(k+1)$.

Good.  I added in that bracketed part because it emphasizes that “$P(k)$ is true” and “$k$ is even or $k-1$ is even” are equivalent statements.

> Then $k+1$ is even or $(k+1)-1$ is even.

Hold on.  This statement is equivalent to $P(k+1)$, which has not been proved yet.  When you say “Then ... ” it sounds like you are saying it follows from previous work.

Well, what do you know at this point?  You know (or rather, you're assuming) that either $k$ or $k-1$ is even.  You want to show that either $k+1$ or $k$ is even.  Try to prove this first:

**Lemma.** If $n$ is an even integer, then $n+2$ is even.

Then see if that lemma helps you with the inductive step.